# 3D Pie diagram visualization

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to make some kind of 3d vizualisation of a pie diagram.

[This is a 2d pie diagram of galaxies scattered by their position on the sky and redshift](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Em4bZ.png)

However, galaxies have 2 angle coordinates, so I want to add depth to this plot, the other angle goes from like 24 to 26 so its not really big compared to the one already plotted. Also, its important that the axes are displayed in the same fashion as the 2d plot

Thanks in advance

btw I made this plot using floating axes, but i havent been able to find some kind of floating axe for 3d plots.

Comment: have you every looked at https://plot.ly/python/ ? It's capable of 3D.

Comment: well you can look at the example with the sphere here http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html but if you really want it to be a pie diagram you will have to do a little more work yourself...